# Ошибка при работе с компаратором

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пишу свой двунаправленный список (шаблонный класс). Нужно организовать вставку с автосортировкой (т.е. чтобы элемент всегда вставлялся на нужное место). Код такой:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
   ...
   template<typename CompT = std::less<T>>
   void insert(T value, CompT comp = CompT())
   {
      // Если вставить надо в начало
      if(comp(value, *begin())
      {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

И на `comp(value, *begin())` я получаю ошибку

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

В пособиях написано так же. Я раньше писал сортировки, всё работало (там было в параметрах шаблона, правда, сразу 2 параметра: `T` и `CompT` - мб из-за этого проблема).

Перепробовал уже все варианты, в т.ч. убирал значения по умолчанию и при вызове сам указывал `std::less<T>` - ничего не помогает.

Comment: Приведите полное сообщение об ошибке, включая следующее за ним подсообщение.

Comment: Имейте в виду, что у вас пропущена одна закрывающая скобка. if(comp(value, *begin()). Должно быть if(comp(value, *begin()))

Comment: Да, спасибо, забыл посмотреть в окно Output. Был метод push_back, в котором вызывалось insert(NULL, value) - имелся ввиду вызов метода insert(iterator where, T value). Прикастовал NULL к iterator - все нормально